# Setting DNS setting for a new domain

Tags: dns, web

I willing to buy a new domain bit I want to know if I can set it up so that I can browse from the new domain to the old domain.

For example

newdomain.com/page == olddomain.com/newdoman/page and so with each page that i will try to visit without having to host for the new domain.
Is this possible trough the DNS settings?

Answer (score 0):

No.

DNS only handles resolving hostnames to IP addresses (although it can alias hosts).

Scheme specific path handling doesn't go anywhere near DNS.

Comment: I have tried it with a cname but then i get ssl errors and it does only work with the root old domain

Comment: Jens, that just confirms what Quentin answered. It can not be done using solely DNS.